# How to run a DHCP Server on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, dhcp

How can I create a DHCP server in a Windows XP environment?

Comment: Windows internet connection sharing could also solve the matter at hand, as an alternative to running a DHCP server

Comment: I presume it's a DHCP server so you can do more than just supply IP addresses - e.g. to perform netbooting of remote systems?

Answer (score 3):

Typically you'd have a Windows Server box doing DHCP addressing, but if you wish to set it up on XP you'll need some additional software. I've used [Dual DHCP DNS Server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dhcp-dns-server/) in the past. It's 100% free and can act as a DNS server as well if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

If your Windows XP network has a Cable or DSL router on it you may already have a DHCP server though it might not be enabled.  Other software solutions work well but they require that the computer hosting the DHCP service be switch on all the time.  A cheap router with a DHCP service (most consumer routers do have DHCP services) in firmware may be a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Tiny DHCP Server](http://www.softcab.com/dhcp-server/index.php) works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

[TFTPD32](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/) has DHCP Server built in

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP has a DHCP server built in (it just isn't enabled). To enable it you will need to tweak the 'IpEnableRouter' option in regedit (google 'IPEnableRouter'). Works perfectly and so little fuss.
I haven't yet found ANYTHING in Windows Server 2003 which isn't present in Windows XP SP3 but hidden away.

Comment: Can you describe the instructions, as opposed to just saying "Google it"?

Answer (score 0):

I'd never heard of Dual DHCP DNS Server before seeing it above. I had tried Tiny DHCP server and it wasn't doing what I wanted. I had tried VirtualBox's built-in DHCP server too. Dual Server did exactly what I wanted with very little fuss.  Now I have a VirtualBox Host-Only Network where all my VM guests can talk w/ each other and with my VM host machine- but which cannot possibly communicate with anything outside of my host machine.  AND now, because of Dual Server, I can now do everything using regular hostnames.  There's not a fixed IP address anywhere in the new setup.  Dual server really worked well for me.

For those who are interested in VirtualBox, my Guest VM setup has two NICs- the first one gets the VBox default NAT subnet, and the second one gets my Vbox Host-only network.  If I want the guest VM's to be able to get out to the internet for OS updates or whatever, I just connect the virtual ethernet cable on the first NIC.  My Vbox Host-only network's built-in DHCP server is DISABLED, so that Dual Server can do the work.  Dual Server runs on my host machine and I bound it to the (static) IP address of the Vbox Host-only network.